# Typescript does not infer undefined as a return type from array.prototype.find

Tags: typescript

I have a project using typescript 3.7.2 and every time i use the "find" method on arrays vs code does not show "undefined" as a possible return type.

```
interface Repository<T, TID> {
  get: (id: TID) => T | undefined;
}

class CustomerRepository implements Repository<Customer, string> {
  private customers: Customer[];

  constructor() {
    this.customers = [
    {
      id: "ID1",
      name: "Generic Customer 1",
      age: 30
    },
    {
      id: "ID2",
      name: "Generic Customer 2",
      age: 40
    },
    {
      id: "ID3",
      name: "Generic Customer 3",
      age: 50
    }
  ]
  }

  get(id: string): Customer | undefined {
    return this.customers.find(customer => customer.id === id);
  }
}
```

It does not matter if i call the "get" method on the repository or call "this.customers.find" inside the repository, it still won't show "undefined" as a possible return type.
This code will compile and then chrash immediately after running:

```
const customer = customerRepo.get("ID4");
console.log(customer.id);
```

This is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es6",
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "lib": ["dom", "es6", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"],
    "noImplicitAny": true
},
"exclude": [
    "./node_modules/**/*",
    "definitions"
]
}
```

Comment: this works fine. if you look for `ID4`, you will get `undefined`, which means it does not exist and you have to handle this in the output. but if you search for something that exists, like `ID3`, you will get the results back

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`undefined` and `null` are absorbed by other types in unions unless the `strictNullChecks` option is specified in `tsconfig`. See [docs](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compileroptions.html) for all options.

If you add the option `undefined` will be present in the return type.

Comment: I was not aware of that. Thank you for clarifying

Comment: A zillion thanks man! Could have gone a really deep rabbit hole with this one if it wasn't for your answer!

Comment: Thank you! I was so confused why VSC seemed to be ignoring the blatantly obviously fact that `Array.find` can return `undefined`. Turns out, I hadn't loaded the folder into VSC that contained the `ts.config`.